# Set consisting of fixed power of elements of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let G be a group. Let n be a fixed natural number. Consider $S=\{g^{n}|g\in G\}$. Is this set a subgroup of G? For n=1 it is the trivial subgroup, for $n\geq 2$ we need the condition that G is abelian to say that this is a subgroup. But I was unable to find a counter example for non- abelian case. Further in non- abelian case how can I get counter examples for each n?

Also motivated by this question I got one more question in mind. Let G be a group. Let n be a fixed natural number. Consider $S=\{g|\exists a\in G$ such that $g=a^{n}\}$. Is this set a subgroup of G? Again for n=1 it is the trivial subgroup. For $n\geq 2$ we need the condition that G is abelian to say that this is a subgroup. For non- abelian case how do I construct counter examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the subset of squares of a group a subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372252/is-the-subset-of-squares-of-a-group-a-subgroup)

Comment: How do I construct for each n? Further what are the counter examples for the second question?

Comment: Your two questions are the same.  The free group on two letters is a counterexample for all $n$, and it should be possible to construct explicit examples using algebraic groups over finite fields, as in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Note that, for $p$-groups it makes sense to consider the subgroup *generated* by these sets, called the "Agemo" and "Omega" respectively: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_and_agemo_subgroup

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.

Comment: You do not need $G$ to be abelian for the set $G^{\{n\}}=\{g^n\mid g\in G\}$ to be a subgroup. If $G$ is abelian, then it is a subgroup, but it may be a subgroup even if $G$ is not abelian. For example, if $G=S_3$ and $n=6$, then the set consists of of only the identity, which is of course a subgroup. More generally, a group $G$ is said to be $n$-abelian if and only if $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ holds for all $a,b\in G$. Being $n$-abelian is, again, sufficient for the subset to be a subgroup.

Comment: @ahulpke: Note that the second set is not the set of elements of exponent $n$ (corresponding to the Omega subgroup), but rather it is again the set of elements that are $n$th powers. OP is just talking about the Agemo subgroup in both cases, as observed by lulu.

Answer (score 5):

> For $n\geq 2$ we need the condition that $G$ is abelian to say that this is a subgroup.

That statement seems to be saying that $\{g^n\mid g\in G\} = G^{\{n\}}$, with $n\geq 2$, is a subgroup *only if* $G$ is abelian. But this is not correct. "$G$ is abelian" is *sufficient*, but not necessary.

For an easy example, consider $G=S_3$ and $n=6$. Then $G^{\{6\}} = \{g^6\mid g\in S_3\} = \{e\}$ is a subgroup, even though $G$ is not abelian.

More generally, a group $G$ is said to be $n$-abelian if and only if $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for all $a,b\in G$. Alperin proved that a group $G$ is $n$-abelian if and only if it is a quotient of a subgroup of a direct product of a group of exponent $n-1$, a group of exponent $n$, and an abelian group. (It is easy to verify that if $G$ is of exponent $n-1$, of exponent $n$, or abelian, then it satisfies $(ab)^n= a^nb^n$; and that the class of groups that satisfy this condition is closed under products, subgroups, and quotients).

If $G$ is $n$-abelian, then we have that $G^{\{n\}}$ is necessarily a subgroup, since it is trivially closed under inverses, contains $e=e^n$, and in the $n$-abelian case we also have $g^nh^n = (gh)^n\in G^{\{n\}}$.

However, a group need not be $n$-abelian for this set to be a subgroup, either. For example, consider the dihedral group of order $8$, which is not $2$-abelian (a group is $2$-abelian if and only if it is abelian). Then $G^{\{2\}} = \{e,r^2\}$, since every element other than $r$ and $r^3$ is of order $1$ or $2$; this is clearly a subgroup of $G$.

Not sure what you mean by "counter-examples for each $n$". If you mean, for each $n$ find a group in which $G^{\{n\}}$ is not a subgroup, then they aren't hard to find, even restricting for finite groups. For odd $n$, the set $(S_n)^{\{n\}}$ contains all transpositions but no cycle of length $n$. I'll let you figure out the even $n$ case.